# Is there a simple way to apply a function to the RHS of a substitution?

Tags: rule

Suppose I have solved a system of equations, resulting in a solution of the form:

```
sol = {{f[a1] -> SomeComplicatedFunction[x, a1]}, {f[a2] -> SomeComplicatedFunction[x, a2]}, {f[a3] -> SomeComplicatedFunction[x, a3]}}
```

I want to use the list of substitutions `sol` later on, but first I want to apply some method `myFunction` to the rhs of the substitution. I.e., the desired output is

```
sol = {{f[a1] -> myFunction[SomeComplicatedFunction[x, a1]]}, {f[a2] -> myFunction[SomeComplicatedFunction[x, a2]]}, {f[a3] -> myFunction[SomeComplicatedFunction[x, a3]]}}
```

I have tried extracting all the RHSs from `sol`, applying `myFunction` to the list, then setting this back to the original `f[]`s, but this seems to be very inefficient. Is there some canonical Mathematica way of applying rules to solutions while keeping the solutions intact?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
sol = {
   {f[a1] -> SomeComplicatedFunction[x, a1]},
   {f[a2] -> SomeComplicatedFunction[x, a2]},
   {f[a3] -> SomeComplicatedFunction[x, a3]}};

sol2 = sol /. Rule[lhs_, rhs_] :> Rule[lhs, myFunction[rhs]]

(* {{f[a1] -> myFunction[SomeComplicatedFunction[x, a1]]}, {f[a2] -> 
   myFunction[SomeComplicatedFunction[x, a2]]}, {f[a3] -> 
   myFunction[SomeComplicatedFunction[x, a3]]}} *)
```

Answer (score 9):

Additional alternatives:

You can use [`MapAt`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MapAt.html) to map `myFunction` at positions `{All, -1, -1}`:

```
sol3 = MapAt[myFunction, {All, -1, -1}] @ sol
```

> {{f[a1] -> myFunction[SomeComplicatedFunction[x, a1]]},
> {f[a2] ->
> myFunction[SomeComplicatedFunction[x, a2]]},
> {f[a3] ->
> myFunction[SomeComplicatedFunction[x, a3]]}}

You can assign new values at desired positions using `Part` assignment:

```
sol4 = sol;
sol4[[All, -1, -1]] = myFunction /@ sol4[[All, -1, -1]];
sol4
```

> same result

Answer (score 1):

You can also replace `SomeComplicatedFunction` with the composition of `myFunction` and `SomeComplicatedFunction`:

```
sol /. SomeComplicatedFunction -> myFunction @* SomeComplicatedFunction
```

> ```
> {{f[a1] -> myFunction[SomeComplicatedFunction[x, a1]]}, 
>  {f[a2] -> myFunction[SomeComplicatedFunction[x, a2]]},
>  {f[a3] -> myFunction[SomeComplicatedFunction[x, a3]]}}
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Or:

```
sol /. Rule -> (Rule[#, myFunction @ #2] &)
```

> ```
> (*
> {{f[a1] -> myFunction[SomeComplicatedFunction[x, a1]]}, 
>  {f[a2] -> myFunction[SomeComplicatedFunction[x, a2]]},
>  {f[a3] -> myFunction[SomeComplicatedFunction[x, a3]]}}
> *)
> ```

Safer:

```
Apply[Rule[#, myFunction@#2] &, sol, {2}]
```

Or:

```
# -> myFunction @ #2 & @@@ # & /@ sol
```

Or:

```
Dataset[Association /@ sol][All, Map@myFunction] // Normal // Normal
```